# Related to sed command

Tags: unix, sed

What does that mean?
 I didn't evaluate this

```
sed -n "s/,*Receivsed,\([0-9]\+\), *Sent,\([0-9]\+\),*/\1\2/p"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It captures the number after Receivsed (sic!) into `\1` and the number after Sent into `\2`, then replaces the whole substring with just these two numbers, and prints the line.

You can try it with

```
echo ',Receivsed,123,Sent,456' |
sed -n "s/,*Receivsed,\([0-9]\+\), *Sent,\([0-9]\+\),*/\1\2/p"
```

In detail:

- `-n` reads the input line by line, but doesn't print anything if not told to
- `,*` matches zero or more commas
- `\(...\)` creates a capture group, groups are numbered from `\1`
- `[0-9]\+` matches one or more digits
- `, *` matches a comma followed by zero or more spaces
- `s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/` replaces PATTERN by REPLACEMENT
- the final `/p` means the result of the substitution is printed if the match was successful